# How do I access all the fields of an imported object?

Tags: jsonnet

```
$ cat foo.libsonnet
{
    local foo = 99,
    bar: [ foo, 101 ]
}
$ cat baz.jsonnet
{
    local foo = import 'foo.libsonnet',
    baz: [foo.foo, foo.bar]
}
$ jsonnet baz.jsonnet
RUNTIME ERROR: field does not exist: foo
        baz.jsonnet:3:11-18     thunk <array_element>
        baz.jsonnet:3:10-28     object <anonymous>
        During manifestation
```

In this example, it is easy to access `bar` field of `foo`. Is there any way for `baz.jsonnet` to access the locals of `foo.libsonnet`?

If the answer is no, how should I implement `foo` and `baz` so that I can access the `foo` field of `foo.libsonnet` in both `foo.libsonnet` and also in `baz.jsonnet`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way for baz.jsonnet to access the locals of foo.libsonnet?

No. Locals are, well, local. They are just names for values available in some lexical scope. In particular object locals can only be accessed directly in the object definition.

If you want to access a value from outside the object, it shouldn't be a local - use a field instead. If you don't want it to be shown when you manifest the object, you can use a hidden field like so:

```
$ cat foo.libsonnet
{
    foo:: 99, // double colon indicates that the field is hidden
    bar: [ self.foo, 101 ]
}
$ cat baz.jsonnet
{
    local foo = import 'foo.libsonnet',
    baz: [foo.foo, foo.bar]
}
$ jsonnet baz.jsonnet
{
   "baz": [
      99,
      [
         99,
         101
      ]
   ]
}
$ jsonnet foo.libsonnet
{
   "bar": [
      99,
      101
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
$ cat foo.libsonnet
{
    foo_parameters: {
        foo: 98
    },

    foo_objects: {
        local foo = $.foo_parameters,

        bar: [ foo.foo, 101 ]
    }
}
$ cat baz.jsonnet
{
    local foo = import 'foo.libsonnet',
    baz: [foo.foo_parameters.foo, foo.foo_objects.bar]
}
$ jsonnet baz.jsonnet
{
   "baz": [
      98,
      [
         98,
         101
      ]
   ]
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097711/how-to-reference-object-properties-and-the-object-itself-in-jsonnet) is essentially the same question and answer.